# Is it possible to add a movieclip over a bitmap of StageWebView

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap, bitmapdata, stagewebview

I want to add a simple spinnerloader(movieclip) over a StageWebView html page for that i converted StageWebView page to bitmap but that didnt work please help me to solve this problem

```
 var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
     var textGoogle:TextField=new TextField();
     var textFacebook:TextField=new TextField()


     textGoogle.htmlText="<b>Google</b>";
        textGoogle.x=300;
        textGoogle.y=-80;        
        addChild(textGoogle);
        textFacebook.htmlText="<b>Facebook</b>";
        textFacebook.x=0;
        textFacebook.y=-80;        
        addChild(textFacebook);
        textGoogles.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goGoogle);
        textFacebooks.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,goFaceBook);
        webView.stage = this.stage;
        webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 100, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
```

function goGoogle(e:Event):void

```
    {
        webView.loadURL("http://www.google.com");
        webView.stage = null;
        webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,handleLoad);
    }

    function goFaceBook(e:Event):void
    {
        webView.loadURL("http://www.facebook.com");
        webView.stage = null;
        webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,handleLoad);
    }

 function handleLoad(e:Event):void
    {
        var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(webView.viewPort.width, webView.viewPort.height,true,0xffffff);
        webView.drawViewPortToBitmapData(bitmapData);
        var webViewBitmap:Bitmap=new Bitmap(bitmapData);
        webViewBitmap.y = 100;
        addChild(webViewBitmap);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible. Once you have created your bitmap:
1. remove the StageWebView from the stage
2. add your bitmap to the stage.
3. add your movie clip to the stage.

Comment: Its worked i add movie clip before loading the bitmap thats the issue really thanks for helping :) :) :)